# Node.js | get unique result from multiple querys

Tags: node.js, sql-server-2008, postgresql

I wrote the following module which connects to postgresql or SQLServer depending a the Type var value:

```
exports.GetQueryResult = function (type, Name,con,callback) {
            var sql='';
            if (Type ='PG') {

                        sql=sql + ' SELECT …………..';
                        pg.connect(con, function(err, client, done) {
                                if(err) {
                                        console.log("Error :" + err);
                                        return callback(err);
                                        }

                                client.query(sql,[Name], function(err, Result) {
                                        if(err) {
                                                    console.log("Error: " +err);
                                                    return callback(err);
                                                }
                                        return callback(null,Result); 
                                        done();
                                });     
                        });
            }
            else
            {    
                        sql=sql + ' SELECT …..';
                        sql.open(con, function (err, conn,done) {
                               if (err) {
                                          console.log("Error :" + err);
                                          return callback(err);
                               }

                               conn.queryRaw(sql,Name, function (err, Result) {
                                          if (err) {
                                                      console.log("Error ejecutando la consulta. Error: " +err);
                                                      return callback(err);
                                          }
                                          callback(null,Result);
                                          done;
                               });

                        });
            }
};
```

I call this function from:

```
var MultiBD = require('./MultiBD.js');
var LayerType=['PG','SQL','PG'];
var con=’’;

for (var i=1;  i<=Layers.length; i++) {    
                        if (Layers[i-1]!=undefined){
                                   con=MultiBD.conexion(LayerType [i-1],server,BD);
MultiBD.GetQueryResult(LayerType[i-1], Name[i-1],con, 
function (err,Result){      
                                                    console.log('Result : ' + Result.rows.length);
                                                    }           
                                    );
                        }        
}
```

The results are:

```
Result : 111

Result : 2888

Result : 5
```

I get three query results. The first one returns 111 rows, the second one 2888 and the third one 5.

What i need is to get only one unique result with all the 3004 rows (111+2888+5).

Regards,

Comment: if you mean unions, the querys are in different database servers..i cant see how to do what you are saying...

Comment: What's stopping you from merging your results?

Comment: i don't know how to merge all my results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need some flow control to wait until all 3 methods have completed their DB calls before printing their results. There are packages for this, either of the callback variety or Promises.

Here is an example using the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) package (which is of the callback variety of flow-control):

```
var async = require('async');
var totalResults = 0;
async.each( Layers, function eachMethod( layer, eachCb ){
  var con = MultiBD.conexion(layer,server,BD);
  MultiBD.GetQueryResult(LayerType[i-1], Name[i-1],con, function (err,Result) {      
    if( err ) return eachCb( err );
    totalResults += Result.rows.length;
    eachCb( null );
  } );
}, function finalEach( eachErr ){
  if( eachErr ) console.log( "There was an error. " + eachErr );
  else console.log( "Result: " + totalResults );

});
```

In this call, a method (the `eachMethod`) is called on every item in the array. The results are stored in a shared variable. When all items have completed, the `finalEach` method is called. Here errors have bubbled up (which you can choose to check or not) and all calls have completed, so we can simply print the value of the shared variable.

Comment: Thank clay for your answer. The problem is that what i need is to merge the results of the query, not the number of rows!

Comment: The code was just an example. Make `totalResults` an object and fill it with the data you need. You may need three different functions to call the DBs if their results are in different formats. The code I provided is for flow control so you're 'done' at the right time (as in, once all data is merged)